# Django authenticate by email

Tags: python, django, django-authentication

I write my own authentication backend in file `project/emailauth.py` with content:

```
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import check_password
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class EmailBackend(object):
    def authenticate(self, username=None, password=None):
        print("Email auth")
        try:
            user = User._default_manager.get(email=username)
            if user.check_password(password):
                return user
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None
        except:
            return None

    def get_user(self, user_id):
        try:
            return User._default_manager.get(pk=user_id)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

In my `project/settings.py` at the end of the file I added the content:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'project.emailauth.EmailBackend',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)
```

I use authenticate methon in `userprofile/views.py`:

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
#...
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password']
            profile = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            if profile is not None:
                login(request, profile)
                return HttpResponseRedirect(redirect_to)
#...
```

The most interesting I notice that console output `Email auth` only when I try to login by username and password if I use email and password there is not output in console. Looks like my custom authenticate fire up after standard method...

Can someone show me where I made a mistake?

Answer (score 0):

It turned out my forms validation block hole login by email (becouse it's check if users exist in database before it try to authenticate)